# What can you "distinguish" between? Distinguishing between things that seem incomparable

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions, ambiguity

Given my lack in vocabulary, I assume the title doesn't make much sense (and I will welcome more suitable suggestions or edits for the title), but, basically, what brings up that question is a pretty vague sentence I run into while trying to translate a paper:

> Impairments in these EI (Emotional Intelligence) abilities have shown signiﬁcant incremental utility in distinguishing between youth with ADHD and controls, above and beyond deﬁcits in various neuropsychological functions

Possibilities that I had in mind were:

1. The distinguishing is between individuals in the young ADHD population
2. The distinguishing is between young people with ADHD and controls

The first one seems okay, although it would also have to mean that there is also distinguishing between controls (which don't say much to me as controls were not mentioned in any way that actually clarifies what they stand for, which also contributes to the unlikelihood of the second possibility.). What keeps me from excluding the second option is the presence of the common structure "Between...and...", but then again, what is the point in distinguishing between things with no apparent criteria, without which they are generally obviously distinguishable?

I would really like to hear from you on that matter, because I am pretty lost here.

Comment: You are distinguishing between youths with ADHD and the youths in the control group who presumably do not have ADHD.

Comment: The point is that using some measure of the "impairments" introduced at the start of the sentence is effective in distinguishing between youths with ADHD and those in the control group.

Comment: Can I suggest "...between youths with ADHD and those without" unless the control group is defined earlier. The use of 'youth' as a mass noun doesn't help which is why I suggest the plural form.

Comment: I am quite disappointed in myself for not detecting the grammatical structure. I guess this is something more intuitive to natives. 
Thank you, you made a great difference.

Comment: Just to make it clear, "control" was only used once before that, in a context of management of responses. Control Groups were yet to be addressed.

Comment: Control groups are a common feature of many medical and sociological studies. I think the audience for the quote would be expected to understand what's meant there from the general context.

Comment: I believe so, but so far I have gone over around 10-20 papers only, and given I don't speak English from birth, there comes a time when I come by a term that, while possibly legitimate, is new to me, and it is inevitable that will discuss what it might mean. I acknowledge the possibility that customary terms or sentences will not make sense to me, whether I know the words consisting them or not. So when I don't manage to detect any references or analogous structures, I consult with you, and I am pretty satisfied with the perspectives shared with me. :)